# Question related to connecting to SQL Server via a subdomain?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, superuser, serverfault

I asked this question *https://superuser.com/questions/677694/how-to-create-subdomain-link-to-sql-server-2008* on SuperUser but haven't really gotten any bites.

I'm curious whether that is the correct Stack Exchange site for that question?

Comment: From there ["tour"](http://superuser.com/about): *"Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users."* I'm not sure if questions about websites belongs there...

Comment: It is not a website though. If you create a database at some web host like GoDaddy, they give you an external link to your DB like `sqldb1234.db.hostedresource.net`. That is what I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: For reference, I asked my question at Pro Webmasters based on Travis J's suggestion and received the answer I needed. It is here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55348/how-to-create-subdomain-link-to-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a question which would be better received on the [Pro Webmasters Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions)

## [image: logo]

> "Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast webmasters focused on how to operate websites. Questions here are commonly about search engine optimization (SEO), domains, and web-hosting." -[Webmaster's topicality](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thank you for the information! I posted the question there and received an answer. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55348/how-to-create-subdomain-link-to-sql-server-2008